# Listening for EyeGesture.WINK automatically activates "wink to take picture" in Google Glass - how to listen for a wink but NOT take a picture

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am building a Google Glass app and I'd like to recognize eye gestures. I wrote an `EyeGestureListener` to trigger on `EyeGesture.WINK`. When I wink, I do indeed get the callback to my function, but simultaneously a picture is taken due to Google's recent update "wink to take a picture".

When I disable this feature in the Settings on my Glass, it then becomes automatically enabled while running my code because apparently just listening for a wink turns on that feature in GDK. Has anyone been able to listen for a wink and NOT activate the camera? I can post my code, but it's mostly just using this : https://github.com/thorikawa/EyeGestureLib